# tempUITextView setText: @"some text" gives an error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, settext

i created a UIView* myView and then i created a UITextVIew *tempUITextView and set its text as

```
[tempUITextView setText:@"some text"];
[myView addSubView: tempUITextView];
```

when i run the code, it gives an error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]:**

Comment: please give more detail description, the declaration of the textview. So that it can be identified.

Comment: Judging by the error tempUITextView is not actually what you think it is. @iPhoneFun is right, show us how you are creating it.

Comment: UIView* myView =[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,90)]autorelease];


UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease];

Comment: Did you find your mistake in "  UITextView* title=[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease]; " ?

Comment: the error was show in **[tempUITextView setText:@"some text"];** reason: '-[UIView setText:]:

Comment: you are assigning textview an uiview - so there won't be any property of setText, use  UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease];

Comment: No, i have correctly assigned textview an UITextView.

Comment: Above your declaration - check it, it's totally wrong. you are assigning (I think you have written) is wrong still you are not accepting your error ?  what does it mean "UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line

```
UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)] autorelease];
```

Replace it with

```
UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do following things:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 180)];//Any frame you want to set
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Given color to differntiate between myView and tempUITextView
UITextView *tempUITextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];//Any frame for tempUITextView in myView
[tempUITextView setText:@"hi"];
[myView addSubview:tempUITextView];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Why has this answer a -1? You clearly made tempUITextView an UIView instead of an UITextView. You even posted it yourself: UITextView* tempUITextView =[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)]autorelease]; *edit, did an up vote

Answer (score -1):

Are you using IBOutlets for the view and textview? If so, please check whether you have connected outlets to wrong object.